# Create this shape using ClipPath CustomClipper

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, clipping

I'm trying to clip a widget using `ClipPath`  `CustomClipper` -> so far I was able to recreate a wave shape

```dart
ClipPath(
        clipper: WaveClipper(),
        child: CustomWidget(),
);
```

```dart
    class WaveClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
      @override
      Path getClip(Size size) {
        var path = new Path();
        path.lineTo(
            0, size.height); 
    
        var firstStart = Offset(size.width / 5, size.height);
       
        var firstEnd = Offset(size.width / 2.25, size.height - 50.0);
       
        path.quadraticBezierTo(
            firstStart.dx, firstStart.dy, firstEnd.dx, firstEnd.dy);
    
        var secondStart =
            Offset(size.width - (size.width / 3.24), size.height - 105);
   
        var secondEnd = Offset(size.width, size.height - 10);
  
        path.quadraticBezierTo(
            secondStart.dx, secondStart.dy, secondEnd.dx, secondEnd.dy);
    
        path.lineTo(
            size.width, 0);
        path.close();
        return path;
      }
    
      @override
      bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
        return false; //if new instance have different instance than old instance
        //then you must return true;
      }
```

but what I would need to achieve is this pink shape shown on this image :

*the top part does not need to be clipped as it's the edge of the screen, only the bottom*

[image: image clip path shape]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not exactly how you want it, but with small adjustments it stays the same, you have to pay attention to where you left off to start correctly

```
class CustomClipperImage extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
  @override
  getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height-70);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, size.height+40,size.width-40, size.height- 
    130);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width+60, size.height-170,size.width, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you see [`flutter_custom_clippers`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers) package? I think its source code will be helpfull.